# Proper way to pivot when pivoted values are strings

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Person    Answer
Kirk      Captain
Kirk      Iowa
Kirk      Command
Spock     Commander
Spock     Shi Kahr
Spock     Sciences
```

I'm trying to figure out what aggregate I can use in the pivot to get me this result:

```
Person    Answer 1     Answer 2     Answer 3
Kirk      Captain      Iowa         Command
Spock     Commander    Shi Kahr     Sciences
```

I used Max, but both lines had the same answers.

Original SQL:

```
Select * From
(
   Select dView.[respondent code], dView.[Course section], dView.[Subject], 
          dView.Course, dView.[Instructor Name], answers.response, 
          formQuestion.Question_Order
   From Denormalized_V as dView
   Inner Join response_sets as rSets on rSets.sctn_id_code = dView.[section code]
   Inner Join responses as answers on answers.set_id = rSets.set_id
   Inner Join questions as questions on questions.question_id = answers.question_id
   Inner Join form_question as formQuestion on formQuestion.question_id = questions.question_id
   where Term = 'ss14' and 
         [Subject] = 'ws' and 
         Course in ('202') and
         ((@Instructors = '<ALL>') or ([Instructor Pid] = @Instructors or [Instructor Pid] = 'ALL')) and  
         [Course Section] in (@Sections) and [Survey Type] <> 'SOCT'
) t
Pivot (max(response) for question_order in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8])) as pvt
```

Comment: `MAX` sounds about right. If you want help on why it didn't work out for you, then please post the query you used

Comment: How do you know what answer is answer 1 , 2 or 3 ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Taking a closer look, I saw that for some reason, I was getting the same respondent code on all the records.  I changed where I get that code from and everything started to work.

Answer (score 2):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(Person VARCHAR(20), Answer VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
('Kirk' ,'Captain'),
('Kirk' ,'Iowa'),
('Kirk' ,'Command'),
('Spock','Commander'),
('Spock','Shi Kahr'),
('Spock','Sciences')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT Person, Answer
      ,'Answer ' + CAST( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Person ORDER BY Answer) AS NVARCHAR(10)) Vals
FROM @TABLE)t
 PIVOT (MAX(Answer)
        FOR Vals 
        IN ([Answer 1],[Answer 2],[Answer 3])
        )P
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ Person ║  Answer 1 ║ Answer 2 ║ Answer 3 ║
╠════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ Kirk   ║ Captain   ║ Command  ║ Iowa     ║
║ Spock  ║ Commander ║ Sciences ║ Shi Kahr ║
╚════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```